# Using RegExp and eval() to replace a value

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to use RegExp to replace a string and `eval()` to execute the object.

In my code below, I'm currently in a `forEach` of `items`.

**`item.url` :** `http://localhost:3000/formation/[[item.id]]/[[item.launch_url]]`

**My code :**

```
<% _.forEach(items, function(item) { %>
   <% _.forEach(tableLineActions, function(tableLineAction) { %>
      <% if (tableLineAction.conditionToShow) { %>

        <% var label = tableLineAction.label; %>

        <% var url = tableLineAction.url.replace(/\[\[item.id\]\]/g, item.id).replace('[[modelName]]', modelName).replace('[[item.seo_url]]', item.seo_url); %> // not reusable code
        
        <% url = eval(url.replace(/\[\[/g, '').replace(/\]\]/g, '')); %> // test of a reusable code

        <li><a href="<%=url%>"><icon class="material-icons"><%=tableLineAction.icon%></icon><%=label%></a></li>
      <% } %>
   <% }); %>
<% }); %>
```

**Error message :** `Invalid regular expression flags`

I found a solution but this one is not maintenable if I want to send severals properties :

`url = url.replace(/\[\[item.id\]\]/g, item.id).replace(/\[\[item.launch_url\]\]/g, item.launch_url)`

With this solution, I need to add a new `replace()` method when a new property is sending and I want something more reusable without specifying all properties to replace.

Comment: Edit in my post with the entire code as desired.

Comment: Per your code, `eval()` is utterly unnecessary. You can just use `url = url.replace(/\[\[|\]\]/g, '');` and call it a day.

Comment: "*I need to use RegExp to replace a string and `eval()` to execute the object.*" - no you absolutely don't. What you actually need is a parser and interpolator for your custom templating scheme.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus the result is not interpreted with this method. With my second solution the result is interpreted.

Comment: So you have a key/value pair which you need to loop and build a dynamic replacement?

Comment: `/*start loop*/ url = url.replaceAll('[['+key+']]', value); /*end loop*/`